# Like condition is not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

**C# windows form :-> Database : Access**

I have made a query somewhat like this

```
Select * from Emp where E_Name Like 'Alok*??????'
```

the above query is for getting records that have **Alok and 6 charachter** in their name.

If I execute this query in access it works fine and fetches the record but when I try it in c#

```
Select * from Emp where E_Name Like 'Alok*??????'
```

Or

```
Select * from Emp where E_Name Like 'Alok%??????'
```

Both of them does not work and i have also tried both type of connection string

```
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
```

And

```
Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: First of all: `that have Alok and 6 more charachter in there name` -> that's not exactly what the expression does - it seems you try to return Names that *start* with `Alok` and have 6 *or more* charachters following - right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this query which works in an Access session ...

```sql
Select * from Emp where E_Name Like 'Alok*??????'
```

When you want a similar query which you run from outside Access using OleDb, change the wild card characters ...

```sql
Select * from Emp where E_Name Like 'Alok%______'
```

But if you actually want only *Alok* followed by exactly 6 characters, use this instead ...

```sql
Select * from Emp where E_Name Like 'Alok______'
```